# In SSMS I can hover over a column name and it gives me the Type. Is there also a simple way to get its source table/query?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SSMS when I am in a script, I can hover over a column name and it will give me the column's type and if it is Null/Non Null.

**Is there a similar simple way to get which table/query in the From clause a column is referenced from (or the alias), if the developer hasn't included it?**

For example the simple query below:

```
SELECT Column1, table1.column2
From 
table1 join 
table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

I can see Column2 is referenced from table1, but Column1 doesnt have a reference. If I hover over column1 it might say Column1 (Varchar,Null).

Is there a simple way for SSMS to tell me if column1 is from table1 or table2   like it does its type.

Comment: It's not pretty, but I think you could get the estimated execution plan and view the xml.  Then search for your column in the `ColumnReference` node.  EX:  `<ColumnReference Database="[Test]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Table2]" Column="Column1" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of an easy implementation in standard SSMS, you could use `sp_help` / `ALT F1` when hovering over the table to check what columns belong to the table.

```
exec sp_help'dbo.table1'
exec sp_help'dbo.table2'
```

or selecting the table & pressing `ALT+F1`

[image]

Result

[image]

These query shortcuts can be found in `options - environment - keyboard - query shortcuts`

[image]

---

**Other options**

You could also look into adding your own custom shortcut in there, or look into external vendors for ssms add ons.

An example of creating your own procedure & shortcut:

```
USE Database
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.FindIfColumnExists
@TableColumn varchar(255)
AS
SELECT t.name,c.name FROM sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE @TableColumn = QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) +'.'+ QUOTENAME(t.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
```

With two ways to run it:

```
EXEC FindIfColumnExists'[dbo].[table1].[Column1]'
```

or
[image]

& `CTRL + F1`

[image]

Comment: They could also ask Microsoft to add that as a feature in SSMS via https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

While not native to SSMS, you could download and install the free version of [SSMSBoost](https://www.ssmsboost.com/VersionCompare).

While viewing your query, highlight the column in question, right-click and choose (Locate object in Object Explorer)

[image]

The SSMS Object Explorer window will put the focus on the exact table and column.